# Calling different sets of Python Functions for different Clients

Tags: python, frontend, integration

I have more than 60 python functions, I want to call the functions from SQL database which in turn linked with front-end. All the python functions necessarily use spark dataframes. Dataframes and intermediate files are stored in cloud. I want to make the system restartable and modular. How to achieve the same? What is the correct design to call the those many python functions based on requirements of different clients (which is selected from front-end, angular js).

I am currently trying to call all the functions from SQL. But I don't know the complete system design to make the system efficient. Am I following the right approach or not? All of these python functions are basically data engineering pipelines.

Comment: well, calling python (especially spark jobs) from a sql call sounds wrong right off the bat!

Comment: Spark jobs are handled in databricks itself. But I want to know if there are any other approaches that we can use to call various python function based on business needs.